# How can you make the a DNS translate an wed domain name into a domain name of your liking?

Tags: dns

I might sound like noob, I'm real new to this.
I use my college LAN to use internet. My college has blocked many websites(movies, games, porn etc).
I'm not sure about the way that it works. VPNs don't connect. And entering directly the IP addresses of websites is also blocked.
so what i was thinking is that if we could somehow type in google.com and make the DNS translate the ip address of steam.com, could that help bypassing?

Answer (score 0):

If the websites ip are locked, this is not a dns filtering so you have nothing to do with dns. If vpn don't connect, some ports are probably locked. So, you should find a vpn that use the port 443 or use a webproxy.

Comment: But using any IP address is blocked even google's ip address is blocked, but when you type in the the website's name, then it works.

Comment: OK. Then you can try to change your dns. For example with google's : 8.8.8.8  8.8.4.4